# Splash page for mobile website

Tags: 6, theming

I am working on a mobile website and I need to have a splash page for 3 sec displayed when the client access the website for the first time. Is there any plugin I can use or what solution can I use.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Put a meta refresh tag in the header of your mobile splash page template:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=http://WHEREYOUREALLYWANTTOGO">
```

This will display the splash page for 3 seconds before moving on to the page you want them to see next.

Comment: Yes that's quite interesting but I have just found [meerkat](http://meerkat.jarodtaylor.com/) which is very easy to setup.